# How to remove # in URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url

My problem is that I use HTML's anchors. These works perfectly, unless the unwanted # signs in URL-s.

So my code looks like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper" id="pageup">
<a href="#pageup"><img src="assets/img/arrow.png" style="width:40px;height:40px;" align="right"></a>
```

And the URL looks like this https://loremipsum.hu/modszerek.html#pageup
I want to remove that # from the URL and repleace it witha /.
I have already try some html things but none of them worked so far. Should I use .htacces file to manipulte the URL?

Comment: *URL fragments* are entirely client-side, nothing .htaccess can do for you here. Sounds like you might want some Javascript behaviour that overrides the default appending of the fragment to the URL.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to remove # ?
.htacess file cannot do the needful for you

Comment: There is no scientific reason behind my motivation. I just dont find it aesthetic in this way. And it can be misleading for the visitors maybe

Comment: If you want to change only href from `#pageup` to `/pageup` then you can use jQuery.

Comment: Well why is `#` in there in the first place then, if it is “unwanted”?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery. Add below code below your `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var getHref = $('#pageup a').attr('href');
    var newHref = getHref.replace('#','/');
    $('#pageup a').attr('href', newHref);
  });
</script>
```